# Why does this problem have an answer of 70 degrees instead of 110?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

So I tried to solve a geometry problem. It says:

Triangle $PAB$ is formed by three tangents to circle $O$ and $\angle APB = 40\deg$, then $\angle AOB$ equals:

(A) 45 deg
(B) 50 deg
(C) 55 deg
(D) 60 deg
(E) 70 deg

I tried to solve the problem and came up with $110 \deg$. But the shown correct answer is $(E)$ $70 \deg$, which is exactly the supplement of my answer. And my interpretation of the problem is that circle with center $O$ is inscribed in triangle $PAB$. That leads to an answer of $110 \deg$ and an obviously obtuse angle of $\angle AOB$.

So which is the correct answer? Are both answers correct?
Geogebra picture of my interpretation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have understood and communicated the question correctly, then your answer of $110^\circ$ is correct.  See the following diagram.

[image]

Since $\triangle PA'O \cong \triangle PB'O$ are right triangles, $\angle A'PO \cong \angle B'PO$ and both have measure $20^\circ$, thus $\angle A'OP \cong \angle B'OP = 90^\circ - 20^\circ = 70^\circ$.  Similarly, $\angle A'OB \cong \angle P'OB$ and $\angle B'OA \cong \angle P'OA$, so $$\angle AOB = \frac{360^\circ - 140^\circ}{2} = 110^\circ.$$

Comment: But, the problem suggests a different interpretation than mine. See [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/triangle-pab-is-formed-by-three-tangents-to-circle-o-and-measuredangle-apb-400/). My real question is, which INTERPRETATION is correct?

Comment: @zixuan Well, because you did not provide the original diagram from the question, I assumed (as you did) that the circle was an incircle to $\triangle APB$.  But seeing the diagram now, it is clear that they intended circle $O$ to be an **excircle**.  Therefore, our diagrams and interpretations are incorrect, although the question should have been clearer when describing the relationship of the triangle to the circle.